# How does mongodb compare/sort by _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How does mongodb apply comparison operators and sorting on _ids? Does it do it by the timestamp portion of the _id? Also, does it make a difference if the objectId was generated on the client or server?

If so, would paging be reliable on this field? e.g. `_id: { $gte: last_idOnPage }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation about [ObjectId()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) you can see that _id is a hexadecimal string which represents 12-byte number which consists of:

- 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- 3-byte machine identifier,
- 2-byte process id, and
- 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Therefore partially you are correct: it uses timestamp to sort values as well. But other parts are also used. Because this string represents a number, mongo just compares numbers to find which one is bigger.

Regarding your second question (does it makes a difference was _id generated by application layer or by database): it does not make any difference. Mongo still compares only numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp is the first portion of `BSON::ObjectId` value. So basically yes, it first sorts by timestamp and then by other parts.

Comment: So, in your opinion, is it good to use for paging? Currently I've come up with `{ _id: { $gte: last_idOnPage, $ne: last_idOnPage } }` as the cleanest way to page based on generation time. Since `BSON::ObjectId`s have a 1 second resolution, I would have to use $ne in conjunction with $gte in order to get other documents for which the _id was generated in the same second, correct?

Comment: Yes, I use it for paging regularly. I don't use the `$ne` part, because there are other data bits besides timestamp. So 1 second resolution does not bother me.

Comment: So, I take it you just use `$gt` since the other data bits ensure that the provided _is is unique enough to where you won't miss other documents who _id was generated during that same second and further?

Comment: Well, let's see. If you query data for current second and you write very intensively (like, 10k inserts / sec), then you *might* skip some records. I don't know how important this is for your app. When querying data in the past (previous second and further), the app should not skip records.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev in a high-insertion scenario, is there a common/typical pagination strategy? Thanks